# Error: Counter button needs to be clicked twice to get from 0 to 1

Tags: reactjs

In React.js, I want to make a simple count button, where each click is a +1,
but on the first click it still gives me 0, and only on the second click does it go up to 1, why is that? And how do I fix it?

```js
class COUNT extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { count : 0 }
    }

    addNumber(){
        setState({count: this.state.count+1})
        console.log(this.state.count)
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={() => addNumber()}>button</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `setState` a bit wrong. Try this `setState({count: this.state.count + 1})` Further more, seems like you are setting state based on previous states (newCount = previousCount + 1), I recommend using [function-style `setState`: `setState(prev => ({count: prev.count + 1}))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494985/setstate-in-react-based-on-current-state)

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam yeah my bad i wrote it wrong here thanks

Comment: I edited your question because it looks like a feature you want to implement!

Comment: @barakooren There is danger using `console.log` immediately after setting states, because `setState` is asynchronous by nature. If your error stems from the `console.log` line, you might want to take a look at my post on a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335232/14426823

Answer (score 0):

I find it unlikely that this code works at all.  Perhaps a copy/paste error?  There were multiple missing `this`'s and (as stated in a comment) a missing `count:`. I believe this should work:

```js
class COUNT extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { count : 0 }
  }

  addNumber(){
    this.setState({state: this.state.count+1})
    console.log('added', this.state.count) // likely prints old value
  }

  render(){
    console.log('rendering', this.state.count) // should print new value
    return(
      <button onClick={() => this.addNumber()}>button {this.state.count}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Note that `setState` will not generally immediate change `this.state`; it queues an update.  See the comments around `console.log`s.  This is maybe what you were seeing with the logs being one number out of date.  I've added a rendering of the count (`{this.state.count}` in the button) to make it clear that it does have the correct value.